# how to check if a button widget exists [kivy]

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am creating buttons dynamically. Constantly when the `get_username()` function is called.
And every time the buttons are duplicated, but I would like only new ones to be added. How can I do that?

```
class Curs(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_username(self):
        with conn:
            cursor=conn.cursor()
            sql=f'''SELECT name_courses
            FROM [courses]
            '''
            cursor.execute(sql)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            print(results)
            for i in range(len(results)):
                self.ids['test'].add_widget(Button(text=str(results[i][0]),size_hint_y=None,id=str(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `clear_widgets()` before create.

```
class Curs(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_username(self):
        with conn:
            cursor=conn.cursor()
            sql=f'''SELECT name_courses
            FROM [courses]
            '''
            cursor.execute(sql)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            print(results)
            self.ids['test'].clear_widgets()
            for i in range(len(results)):
                self.ids['test'].add_widget(Button(text=str(results[i][0]),size_hint_y=None))
```